# Elasticsearch UTF-8 characters in search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed record:

"žiema"

Elastic search settings:

## index:

```
cmpCategory: {type: string, analyzer: like_analyzer}
```

## Analyzer

```
analysis:
    char_filter:
        lt_characters:
            type: mapping
            mappings: ["ą=>a","Ą=>a","č=>c","Č=>c","ę=>e","Ę=>e","ė=>e","Ė=>e","į=>i","Į=>i","š=>s","Š=>s","ų=>u","Ų=>u","ū=>u","ž=>z", "Ū=>u"]
    analyzer:
        like_analyzer:
            type: snowball
            tokenizer: standard
            filter   : [lowercase,asciifolding]
            char_filter : [lt_characters]
```

What I want:

By keyword "`žiema`" found record "`žiema`" AND by keyword "`ziema`" also found record "`žiema`", how to do that ?

I try execute characters replace and filter `asciifolding`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try indexing your field twice like it is shown in the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html#_retaining_meaning).

```
PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
  "properties": {
    "cmpCategory": { 
      "type":           "string",
      "analyzer":       "standard",
      "fields": {
        "folded": { 
          "type":       "string",
          "analyzer":   "like_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so the `cmpCategory` field is indexed as standard with diacritics, and the `cmpCategory.folded` field is indexed *without* diacritics.

And while searching, you do the search on *both* indexes as such:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "most_fields",
      "query":    "žiema",
      "fields": [ "cmpCategory", "cmpCategory.folded" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if the `char_filter` is necessary since the `asciifolding` filter already does that transformation.

Comment: I need replace characters not in keyword, but in indexed data it's possible ?